# Concatenate output of multiple commands and use them as input to another command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to figure out how to get a list of pids of multiple processes:

```
pidof proc1

1234 4321 7665

pidof proc2

3312 445
```

and take all this pids, where there are multiple instances of multiple processes and combine them and then feed them all into the kill command. Since kill can take multiple pids as input, I was hoping I could do this without a for-each loop:

```
kill -SIGKILL echo $(pidof proc1; pidof proc2)
```

but I just get "bash: kill: echo: arguments must be process or job IDs" error message.
I'm very new to bash scripting so I'm sure there's just something obvious I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `echo`. It's unnecessary and is the reason for the error message since the word `echo` isn't a PID.

```
kill -SIGKILL $(pidof hsd-tab; pidof firefox-browser)
```

Better, `pidof` can take multiple program names:

```
kill -SIGKILL $(pidof hsd-tab firefox-browser)
```

Still better, use `pkill` to kill programs by name. It's like `kill` + `pidof`.

```
pkill -SIGKILL hsd-tab firefox-browser
```

Try to avoid killing programs with `-SIGKILL` or `-9` unless you absolutely have to. It doesn't give them a chance to shut down cleanly. It's almost always overkill and is a bad habit. I would go with:

```
pkill hsd-tab firefox-browser
```

Comment: thank you! I thought I had tried that and thought it didn't work because it outputs "kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]" when running the command without the echo, but the processes are infact gone. How can I get it to not output that message?

Answer (score 1):

On the face of it, you need to eliminate `echo`:

```
kill -SIGKILL $(pidof hsd-tab; pidof firefox-browser)
```

That should give you two (or more) PIDs separated by spaces.  I believe `kill` was complaining about the `echo`, which is neither a PID nor a job ID (those look like `%1`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `echo`. `$()` takes the stdout of the commands run already.